# Flutter app crashes on startup on Android 12

Tags: android, flutter, crash, android-12

I have published an app on Google Play and it is being used regularly. In the last update, I have released updated both, compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31.

I have seen that users with an Android version less than 12 do not have any issues with the app, while those with an Android version 12 are facing an app crash whenever they try to open the app.

This is the message I get from Google Play Store:

[image]

Did anyone face a similar problem? Would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Yes the latest update has caused some trouble. Could you share the error message you are getting? While at it, if it involves the kotlin version the just navigate to android/build.gradle and update the **ext.kotlin_version to 1.6.10**

Comment: @O'neya I am not getting any error message. It just crashes in both, debug and release mode. One more note, I have updated the Kotlin version to 1.6.10.

The only message I get is from Google Play Store saying "Something went wrong with the app. The app closed because this app has a bug.". I have updated the question with a screenshot. Please check it.

Comment: After updating the target version to 31 did you implement the behavioral changes mandatory in android 12 . For more info check this link  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12

Comment: @HimanshiThakur thank you for the link. I will update you after I try to fix the issue following the instructions

Comment: @HimanshiThakur I have solved the issue and answered my own question. Thanks once again for the link.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Here is what I did:

1. I have added `android:exported="true"` in my AndroidManifest.xml to all activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters
2. I have added `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'` in the `dependencies` section of my app level build.gradle (`android/app/build.gradle`)

After that my app was working regularly on Android 12 and these changes did not affect the lower Android versions

Comment: I already did 'android:exported="true"' stuff. But below one didn't. After did No.2, it works well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nothing works for me...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work permission handler. Check this https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: It was nothing about the permissions. The answer above worked

Answer (score -6):

try to implement  firebase_crashlytics in your project. It will give you a better idea of why your app is crashing!!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31486134)